# A minecraft command that gives you a villager spawn egg with custom trades 1.16

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make an overpowered kit that uses one command and I need the custom trade villager to be in a pre-filled chest and I've tried

```
/give @p chest{BlockEnityTag:{Items:[{Slot:2,id:villager_spawn_egg,Count:127,tag:{EntityTag:{VillagerData:{profession:armorer,level:5,type:plains},Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:stick,Count:1},sell:{id:emerald_block,Count:64},maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:emerald,Count:1},sell:{id:stick,Count:64},maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:stick,Count:1},sell:{id:paper,Count:64},maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:stick,Count:1},sell:{id:gunpowder,Count:64},maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:stick,Count:1},sell:{id:oak_log,Count:64},maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:stick,Count:1},sell:{id:netherite_block,Count:64},maxUses:9999999}]}}}}]}} 1
```

it seems to be working but it gives nothing in the chest and I'm not sure if it can be done and I have a summon command for the villager

```
/summon villager ~ ~1 ~ {VillagerData:{profession:armorer,level:5,type:plains},Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:stick,Count:1},sell:{id:emerald_block,Count:64},maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:emerald,Count:1},sell:{id:stick,Count:64},maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:stick,Count:1},sell:{id:paper,Count:64},maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:stick,Count:1},sell:{id:gunpowder,Count:64},maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:stick,Count:1},sell:{id:oak_log,Count:64},maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:stick,Count:1},sell:{id:netherite_block,Count:64},maxUses:9999999}]}}
```

both with the chest command

```
/give @p chest{BlockEnityTag:{Items:[{Slot:2,id:villager_spawn_egg,Count:127}]}} 1
```

and `Count:127` is possible I checked

Comment: Oh and I have a link to the kit which is really cool (I will be editing the doc sometimes) https://docs.google.com/document/d/16SGV_34mpvk0L9GpyyphbnQjaZ8sjuewRqsXET2k7-8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mispelled `BlockEntityTag` as `BlockEnityTag`.

Comment: oh god I gotta check my spelling

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

```
/summon villager ~ ~1 ~ {VillagerData:{profession:librarian,level:2,type:plains},Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:stick,Count:1},sell:{id:emerald,Count:1},maxUses:9999999}]}}
```

Comment: Could you explain the command?

Answer (score -1):

```
/summon villager ~ ~1 ~ {VillagerData:{profession:farmer,level:2,type:plains},CustomName:"\"not too lucky villager\"",Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:emerald,Count:64},sell:{id:golden_apple,Count:50},maxUses:9654555039},{buy:{id:cobblestone_slab,Count:1},sell:{id:emerald_block,Count:1},maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:cobblestone,Count:5},sell:{id:iron_helmet,Count:1,tag:{display:{Name:"\"not too lucky helmet\""},Enchantments:[{id:protection,lvl:4},{id:respiration,lvl:3},{id:aqua_affinity,lvl:1},{id:thorns,lvl:3},{id:unbreaking,lvl:3},{id:mending,lvl:1},{id:vanishing_curse,lvl:1}]}},maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:cobblestone,Count:5},sell:{id:iron_chestplate,Count:1,tag:{display:{Name:"\"not too lucky chesplate\""},Enchantments:[{id:protection,lvl:4},{id:thorns,lvl:3},{id:unbreaking,lvl:3},{id:mending,lvl:1},{id:vanishing_curse,lvl:1}]}},maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:cobblestone,Count:5},sell:{id:iron_leggings,Count:1,tag:{display:{Name:"\"not too lucky leggings\""},Enchantments:[{id:protection,lvl:4},{id:thorns,lvl:3},{id:unbreaking,lvl:3},{id:mending,lvl:1},{id:vanishing_curse,lvl:1}]}},rewardExp:0b,maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:cobblestone,Count:5},sell:{id:golden_boots,Count:1,tag:{display:{Name:"\"not too luck boots\""},Enchantments:[{id:soul_speed,lvl:3},{id:protection,lvl:4},{id:feather_falling,lvl:4},{id:thorns,lvl:3},{id:depth_strider,lvl:3},{id:unbreaking,lvl:3},{id:mending,lvl:1},{id:vanishing_curse,lvl:1}]}},rewardExp:0b,maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:cobblestone,Count:5},sell:{id:iron_sword,Count:1,tag:{display:{Name:"\"not too lucky sword\""},Enchantments:[{id:smite,lvl:5},{id:knockback,lvl:2},{id:fire_aspect,lvl:2},{id:looting,lvl:3},{id:sweeping,lvl:3},{id:unbreaking,lvl:3},{id:mending,lvl:1},{id:vanishing_curse,lvl:1}]}},rewardExp:0b,maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:cobblestone,Count:5},sell:{id:iron_pickaxe,Count:1,tag:{display:{Name:"\"not too lucky pickaxe\""},Enchantments:[{id:efficiency,lvl:5},{id:unbreaking,lvl:3},{id:fortune,lvl:3},{id:mending,lvl:1},{id:vanishing_curse,lvl:1}]}},maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:cobblestone,Count:5},sell:{id:iron_axe,Count:1,tag:{display:{Name:"\"not too lucky axe\""},Enchantments:[{id:smite,lvl:5},{id:efficiency,lvl:5},{id:unbreaking,lvl:3},{id:fortune,lvl:3},{id:mending,lvl:1},{id:vanishing_curse,lvl:1}]}},rewardExp:0b,maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:emerald,Count:1},sell:{id:potion,Count:1,tag:{Potion:"minecraft:weakness"}},maxUses:9999999}]}}
```

Comment: Hi Ojus, can you please elaborate on your answer? Just posting code without explanation is usually frowned upon.